# How to send a process to background and foreground?

Tags: command-line, job-control

If I do `ping google.com &`, the process goes into the background and keeps showing me the ping details. I can still use terminal with other commands, but the output from ping and output from other commands get mixed up (which is not a problem), but I can't terminate this ping process at all.

For that I want to bring it to the foreground and then press ctrl + c or something. I tried using `fg`, but it didn't work either. So how do I make `ping google.com &` come back into foreground after I hit return key at the end of my ping command?

Comment: It seems like the problem you actually want to solve is killing a background job; there's no need to bring it into the foreground. Use `jobs` to find the Job ID `jid` of the background process, and then just do `kill %jid` to kill it.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`fg` is the correct command to foreground a job, but if there is more than one job running you should specify the job number. If you type only `fg`, the last backgrounded job (considered the current job by the shell) will be brought to foreground.

Get the current jobs:

```
$ jobs
[1]+     ping google.com &
```

Foreground the job by specifying the number:

```
fg %1
```

The command may be broken up by output from the running process, but it will still work, you can ignore the interruption.

Then hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to interrupt and stop the process

As mentioned in a comment, you can also send signals by job number, for example `kill %1`

For completeness, if you didn't use the `&` at the time of calling the process, you can send it to the background by first freezing with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> and then typing `bg`

Comment: Simply `fg` without an argument seems to work too, at least when only having one background job.

Comment: @CedricReichenbach edited!

Comment: does also work with the PID. Get it with `jobs -l` and then `fg <PID>`.